# Pass function parameter variable through get or post from PHP on JQuery Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, parameters

I have a JQuery function to load a .php page and place it in a div every second:

```
function Load_external_content()
{
$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
    $('#external_page_content_displayer').load(URL);
}

setInterval('Load_external_content()', 1000);
```

URL is just the actual url, but I'd rather not display it here.

I have a separate php page that includes this script.  How can I take a javascript parameter into the function ("") to be a variable that I can access via get (or if not post) on URL.

I know very little JQuery and am not too quite at JavaScript, so the more 'spelt out' the answer is the better :).

Thank you in advance for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example available on jQuery's documentation website.

```
$( "#objectID" ).load( "test.php", { "choices[]": [ "Jon", "Susan" ] } );
```

https://api.jquery.com/load/

The extra "data" will be appended in the query_string, as .load uses get.

If you wish to use post, you have to do the load functionality yourself.

```
$.post(url, data, function(response){
    $('#external_page_content_displayer').html(response);
});
```

Comment: I am happy to use get.  Assuming the parameter is called 'convo' and I want it to be referred to in the php as '$_GET["convo"]', what would the code be?

Comment: Would it be ... .load(URL, { "convo": convo }

Comment: Yes, that would be equivalent to  URL + "?convo=" + convo